# Video Background demora para carregar (wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Olá!
Por favor... O vídeo da tela inicial do meu site em wordpress (http://agenciaiddigital.com.br/) demora muito para carregar. E o gif preloader termina de carregar antes do vídeo. Alguém sabe me dizer se existe algum código ou plugin para resolver este problema?
Obrigado!

Comment: Não consegui ver seu vídeo, mas as vezes é questão de hospedagem/arquivo muito grande/codigo ruim para implementar o video. Ví tbm que foi desenvolvido por https://artnaweb.com.br/, por que não envia um e-mail perguntando? talvez respondam.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas dicas:

1- O vídeo é extremamente grande, não importa o plugin que tu use, se usar um vídeo tão grande vai demorar, para isso reduza o vídeo a alguns segundos, pois ele é só um fundo de tela e ele está ali para decorar, não para assistirem;

2- Como ele tem uma tela transparente na frente, dá para reduzir bastante a resolução dele que não vai dar para notar;

3- Fiz o teste dele no [Google Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=pt-BR&url=http%3A%2F%2Fagenciaiddigital.com.br%2F&tab=desktop) test, sugiro que analise a relação custo/benefício das sugestões:

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                $('section#content').style.display = 'block';
            }
</script>
<style media="screen">
            section#content{
                display: none;
            }
</style>
```

Creio que isso vai ajudar. O código acima basicamente vai esconder tudo o que estiver dentro da "section" de id "content" até que todos os elementos da página sejam carregados (o que inclui estilos, imagens e até vídeos). Quando tudo for carregado, o "window.onload" será disparado, setando o display da section content para block, exibindo-a na tela.
Ideal que você coloque este código antes do conteúdo do `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser varias coisas...
vídeo muito extenso...
Pode Estar em alta resolução. (isso deve ser analisado para ficar ideal para web.)
Esta usando uma CDN?
Recomendo também um plugin de carregamento.
E para terminar..
Hospede o video externamente.